# RESTEASY Image Resize with ImageIo.read(InputStream) returns Null BufferedImage

Tags: image, upload, resize, bufferedimage, resteasy

Here are details of my problem:

**Problem:** I am using RestEasy to Upload Resized Thumbnails from a Multipart Form InputStream. The BufferedImage Object to feed into Scalr.resize returns **NULL** value. In the below code, **BufferedImage img is NULL** all the time.

Can you help me figure out how can I get this right.

My Code Snippet:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.jboss.resteasy.annotations.providers.multipart.MultipartForm;
import org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.IIOImageProviderHelper;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import com.kryptonite.aws.AWSHelper;
import com.kryptonite.utils.DAO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.imgscalr.Scalr;
:
:
:
:
        @POST
        @Consumes( MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA )
        public String uploadImage(@MultipartForm InputStream image) throws IOException {
            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(image);
            BufferedImage thumbnail = Scalr.resize(img,Scalr.Method.AUTOMATIC, Scalr.Mode.FIT_TO_WIDTH,150, 100, Scalr.OP_ANTIALIAS);
            thumbnail.createGraphics().drawImage(thumbnail, 0, 0, null);
            ImageIO.write(thumbnail, "jpg", new File("/temp/test.jpg"));
             return key;    
        }
```

Comment: Looking at your imports, it seems your code is doing way too many things at once.. Try breaking the problem down to smaller, fixable problems, and solve one at a time. Like, instead of reading the image scaling, etc, try just writing that input stream directly to disk. Try opening the file in an external program. Verify that the data you are feeding to `ImageIO.read()` is a valid image.

Comment: Bonus tip: The line `thumbnail.createGraphics().drawImage(thumbnail, 0, 0, null);` is a) redundant (why draw an image onto itself?), b) a resource leak, as there is no matching call to `Graphics.dispose()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging around, here is what worked for me:

Use MultipartFormDataInput as input

and the code can look similar to:

```
       Map<String, List<InputPart>> uploadForm = images.getFormDataMap();
        List<InputPart> inputParts = uploadForm.get("uploadedImage");
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        BufferedImage reimg = null;
        for (InputPart inputPart : inputParts) {                     
            try {            
                MultivaluedMap<String, String> header = inputPart.getHeaders();
                if (fileName == null){
                key = "nutped_"+ new Date().getTime()+"_"+getFileName(header);
                } else {
                    key=fileName;
                }
                inputStream = inputPart.getBody(InputStream.class,null);
                InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
                reimg = Scalr.resize(ImageIO.read(is), Method.SPEED, size, OP_ANTIALIAS, OP_BRIGHTER);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        //convert BufferedImage to InputStream
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(reimg, "png", baos);
        InputStream isReimg = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
```

Comment: What is `images` in your code? Can you post the entire method?

Answer (score 0):

With a MediaType `multipart/form-data` your request payload is splitted in multiple parts and may look like this:

```
POST /some-resource HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=AaB03x

--AaB03x
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="description"

... description of the image ...

--AaB03x
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="img1.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

... content of img1.jpg ...
--AaB03x--
```

If you just use the `InputStream` of the request you need to parse this on your own but you typically don't want to and use `MultipartFormDataInput` or like you tried `@MultipartForm`. Here you need to map the request payload to a POJO like this:

```
public class ImgUpload {

  @FormParam("description")
  private String description;

  @FormParam("file")
  @PartType("image/jpeg")
  private InputStream file;

}
```

Please check also the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.1.GA/userguide/html/Multipart.html#multipartform_annotation) or [this example](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/rest/resteasy/resteasy-file-upload-example/).

Comment: Apologies for the missing out to state earlier.... I do have a request mapped to POJO in exactly the format you mentioned. And now I tried removing the MEDIATYPE MULTIPART FORM DATA. Still no luck.. Is there a better way to upload image and resize on server in RestEasy?

Comment: How do you upload the image? Can you add some client code?